# CSS: select parent element when child a:active?

Tags: html, css, dom

Most if not all CSS selectors effect a child element of a parent, what I need to do is select the parent when the child 'a' is in an active state. Please see HTML below:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="row-1">
        <td class="col-1 descriptionClass">
            <div class="views-field views-field-title">
                <span class="field-content">
                    <a href="/listen-again/2128">a thing...</a>
                </span>  
            </div>          
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to select "`td class='col-1 descriptionClass'`" when "`a href='/listen-again/2128'>a thing.../a`" is active.

Have seen this: [Selecting Parent of a Child in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9425133/selecting-parent-of-a-child-in-css) but need to use CSS, not JS or Jquery.

Please note there is little I can do to edit the HTML itself as I am using a content management system (Drupal). I have tried a number of selectors but nothing working to date.

Any (constructive) input most appreciated.

Comment: Plain and simple, you can't using pure CSS.

Comment: CSS does NOT have a parent selector

Comment: Sadly, this isn't possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector. Maybe in CSS 4.

Comment: You need to solve this problem at the Drupal level instead of at the CSS level (since you can't solve this problem with CSS alone). Or, you can use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very sorry to break it to you, but there is no way to select a parent in CSS.

You may find the discussion in [this article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors) interesting if you're wondering why.

Comment: I knew about the right to left evaluation, and it makes sense in the context of the DOM tree structure - is this not the quickest way to evaluate...?